# General solution of second Maxwell equation

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, maxwell-equations

The second Maxwell equation can be written as $$\partial_{[\gamma}F_{\mu\nu]}=0$$
We know $F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu $ satisfies above equation. My question: is this the only solution of the equation or there can be more solution as well but they're rejected in electrodynamics maybe on physical grounds?

Comment: Those should be square brackets, not parentheses, to denote *anti*symmetrization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Written in the language of differential-forms, the equation reads $dF=0$ ("$F$ is a **closed** form"). You're asking if that implies that $F= dA$ for some $A$ ("$F$ is **exact**"). This is always true locally, but not necessarily globally, and depends on the topology of the spacetime manifold. The subject exploring the difference between the two is called *Cohomology theory*.

see:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_descriptions_of_the_electromagnetic_field#Differential_forms_approach

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomology